# gem ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

gem ransack についての質問です

ransack の検索結果の表示フォームって
table 構造のみなのでしょうか。

自分は、普通にeachでやってみたのですが、フィルタリングされませんでした。
悪い部分を教えていただければ幸いです。

```
- @posts.each do |post|
  .form-group
    .row
    .responsive
        .responsive.input-group
          .responsive.input-group-btn.well
            .responsive.well
              ul
                li
                  = "No. #{post.id}"
                  = "\s/\s"
                  = sort_link(@q, :subject) + ":"
                  = post.subject
                  = "\s/\s"
                  = sort_link(@q, :date) + ":"
                  = post.date
            - if post.picture.present?
              .img-responsive.well alt="Responsive image"
                = link_to image_tag(post.picture.url, width: 250, height: 250), post
            - if post.video.present?
              .img-responsive.well alt="Responsive image"
                = link_to image_tag(post.video_url(:screenshot), width: 250, height: 250), post
            - if post.body.present?
              p.post_text.well.responsive
                = sort_link(@q, :summary) + ":\s"
                strong= post.body

            .input-group
              p.pull-right
               = link_to '詳細', post , :class => "btn btn-primary"
              - if admin_user_signed_in?
                = link_to '編集', edit_post_path(post) , :class => "btn btn-success"
                = link_to '削除', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: '本当に削除しますか？' } , :class => "btn btn-warning"
```

Comment: ransack についてお尋ねでしたら、使用部分
(`@posts = SomeModel.ransack()`) の部分を追記されると良いと思います。
view で制限を受けることはないはずです。